# SSMS extensibility/addin - get current database and server

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, add-in, ssms

I am trying to write a SSMS addin for a custom auditing requirement (need to audit all queries ran by users in a production environment). I have the .addin file located in the appropriate folders and it hits the breakpoints in my Connect.Exec method and I am able to get the query statements under selection from the active document. However I am not sure if there is any property or method that I could look up to get the database name and the server the user was connected to ?

Comment: why reinvent the wheel in .addin format?

Comment: auditing & compliance reasons primarily

Comment: Auditing eh? What happens when someone runs a query through sqlcmd?

Comment: yeah, we thought about it. the OPS team have some solution in place - where they somehow restrict access to the path of this tool using AD policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some skimming through codeplex for 4 hours, downloading each project and analyzing the code gave me the answer I need. I hope this helps someone someday (although I agree with @Mitch if SQL Server Audit works for you, you should try that out first) ..

Add reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.RegSrvrEnum.dll and SqlWorkBench.Interfaces (located somewhere in your C:\ProgramFiles..\SQL Server.. -). Make sure you have installed the SDK for the tools. I have only tested this for SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Then the below code should do the trick (your welcome!)

```
IScriptFactory scriptFactory = ServiceCache.ScriptFactory;
CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo connectionIfno = scriptFactory.CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo;
UIConnectionInfo conn = connectionIfno.UIConnectionInfo;
Debug.WriteLine("{0}::{1}", conn.ServerName, conn.AdvancedOptions["DATABASE"]);
```

Comment: +1 Great that you followed up and added your solution.

Comment: @Console.WriteLine any insight into why the ServiceCache.ScriptFactory property would throw a null reference exception? Did you encounter this?

Comment: @test no, it has never come up null for me. Do you have a stack trace ? Are you targeting SSMS 2014 ?

Answer (score 1):

> ...need to audit all queries ran by users in a production environment

That's what [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) was designed for (SQL Server 2008 onwards):

> Auditing an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine or an
>   individual database involves tracking and logging events that occur on
>   the Database Engine. SQL Server audit lets you create server audits,
>   which can contain server audit specifications for server level events,
>   and database audit specifications for database level events. Audited
>   events can be written to the event logs or to audit files.

Any auditing solution must run  at the Database Engine, not clients (for obvious reasons!).

Also, normal users should have (at most) read access to Production via SSMS (via login/role permissions), thereby ensuring they can't change anything. That seems preferable to logging the fact after it happened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mitch ! We did try it and ran into some issues. Our infrastructure is a little bit complex than a usual system where in we have around 400 to 500 databases on a single sql server instance and auditing everything using the SQL Server Audit seems to have a performance impact.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain some more? Also, do users have write access to Production?

Comment: Nope not all but we use an external tool to grant access for upto 8 hours (I would need a ticket # to get access which is all an external workflow) but right now this is driven off a group policy. So despite me requesting access, if you and I were in the same AD group you also get the access to the database although in theory you don't know about it which is all a different problem that we are also trying to eliminate to use individual accounts instead of group policy. As you can possibly imagine this shared permission is a nightmare ..